# Помогите сверстать loading circle

Tags: html, css

Помогите сверстать такое:

[image: лоадер]

Каждое разорванное кольцо(*неполное*) должно крутиться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Следуя примеру **Stranger in the Q**,  я создал похожую анимацию как на картинке. Да , знаю, некоторые отличия есть , но мне новый вариант понравился   больше. Посмотреть его можно  тут https://codepen.io/KS_/pen/GRKZRxG

```html
<svg viewbox=-50,-50,100,100 style="height:100vh" fill=none stroke-width=1.3>
  <circle r=46 stroke-dasharray="1000 1000" stroke=black>
<svg viewbox=-50,-50,100,100 style="height:100vh" fill=none stroke-width=1.3>
  <circle r=46 stroke-dasharray="100 100" stroke=black>
        <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" 
                          type="rotate" to="360" dur="3s" 
                          repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </circle>
  <circle r=37 stroke-dasharray="100 100" stroke=black>
        <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" 
                          type="rotate" to="360" dur="4s" 
                          repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </circle>
  <circle r=28 stroke-dasharray="30 10 30" stroke=green>
        <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" 
                          type="rotate" to="360" dur="5s" 
                          repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </circle>
  <circle r=19 stroke-dasharray="10 10" stroke=magenta>
        <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" 
                          type="rotate" to="360" dur="6s" 
                          repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </circle>
</svg>
  </circle>
  <circle r=37 stroke-dasharray="70 50" stroke=gray>
        <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" 
                          type="rotate" to="-360" dur="1s" 
                          repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </circle>
  <circle r=28 stroke-dasharray="10 50 00 00" stroke=black>
        <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" 
                          type="rotate" to="360" dur="5s" 
                          repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </circle>
      <circle r=17 stroke-dasharray="11 10 00 00" stroke=black>
      <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" 
                          type="rotate" to="-360" dur="4s" 
                          repeatCount="indefinite" />
      </circle>
  </svg>
```

Comment: Ну, если по примеру, то неплохо бы отметить как-то - а то моветон получается. Имхо, конечно.

Comment: Просьба включать скриншоты и код непосредственно в сообщения, а не ссылками.

Answer (score 5):

Как то так?

```html
<svg viewbox=-50,-50,100,100 style="height:100vh" fill=none stroke-width=1.3>
  <circle r=46 stroke-dasharray="100 100" stroke=red>
        <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" 
                          type="rotate" to="360" dur="3s" 
                          repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </circle>
  <circle r=37 stroke-dasharray="50 100" stroke=blue>
        <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" 
                          type="rotate" to="360" dur="4s" 
                          repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </circle>
  <circle r=28 stroke-dasharray="5 10 20 30" stroke=green>
        <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" 
                          type="rotate" to="360" dur="5s" 
                          repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </circle>
  <circle r=19 stroke-dasharray="5 10" stroke=magenta>
        <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" 
                          type="rotate" to="360" dur="6s" 
                          repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Спасибо за старания, но **это не похоже на то, что было на картинке**

Comment: А здесь и не фриланс биржа, вам дали отличный пример

Comment: Ну за пример спасибо